# Android Studio: inconsistent automatic including of C++ stdlib headers

Tags: c++, android-studio, compiler-errors, compilation, include

A colleague and I are both on MacBooks running the current Android Studio (3.1.2).

The project (identical source code & Build files) builds on my machine, fails on his.

The error is that a particular C++ file is using `std::vector` and `assert`, which the compiler is failing to find.

And the solution is simply to `#include <vector>` and `#include <assert.h>`

I'm trying to figure out why it runs on my system but not his.

I'm looking through Android Studio's settings for some 'automatically include C++ stdlib' compiler setting, but I can't see anything.

Comment: Are any other standard header files included?  Standard header files may (or may not) include other standard header files.

Comment: It's possible. But my question is: How does the discrepancy arise?  The source code / build-scripts are identical.  And we are both using the latest version of Android Studio.

Comment: I think the three (so far) 'vote-to-close'rs have maybe jumped the gun. This is a perplexing code issue. It has two senior developers stumped this end. This is the kind of situation this site is designed to help with. At least please have the courtesy to justify your vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the same version of the NDK? The default STL changed recently (from gnustl to libc++). Like @Richard Critten points out, the most likely case is that one of the headers you're including is including vector/assert.h, but your coworker is using a different STL where that is not the case.

> I'm looking through Android Studio's settings for some 'automatically include C++ stdlib' compiler setting, but I can't see anything

I would be *incredibly* surprised if this feature existed.